# How do I find what's causing python to stop with no error like it was suddenly terminated but has no error info?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyodbc, palantir-foundry

I'm connecting to a palantir-foundry db using pyodbc. That means it's using their custom odbc driver (windows).

It sometimes gave me timeout errors, so I tried all I could to minimize anything that would let it time out.  There's roughly 2 million records to download, with some large text fields, so I can't put it all in memory using fetchall; I pulled the data as consistently as I can.  Sometimes it works fine, but mostly it gets to a number (like 13000 or 4000) and then python is suddenly quit/ended.  No error info, no timeout listed, nothing.  I know it didn't finish, because it doesn't write the last line to the log file or the output window (printing that the export is done).  How can I track down what the cause is without any exception information?

I tried using odbc tracing, but it slowed things down enough (from writing to the log?) that the only errors I ever saw in it were timeouts.  I've got a lot of try except blocks, and I even once tried wrapping the main function call in a try except block, but it didn't do anything either.

I've never had it suddenly stop on me when stepping  through the code (using VSCode); timeout, yeah, but not suddenly die silently  like it does when I simply run it.  Maybe I don't get far enough along?

Here's the code.

```
import csv
import datetime, time
from string import ascii_uppercase
import shutil, os, json, re
import pyodbc
import logging
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from queue import Queue

#set vars
server = r'<server>'
tokenpwd = '<key>'
cnxnString = r'Driver=FoundrySqlDriver;baseUrl='+server+';pwd='+tokenpwd+';'
base_folder = 'C:\\Python\\'
columns_file = 'clientData_export_columns.txt'
count_file = 'results_count.json'
output_file = f'C:\\bin\\clientData_Data.csv'
QRY_STR = r'SELECT * FROM "<server table name>"'
ROW_BATCH_SIZE = 500
log_file = base_folder + f'\\LOGS\\clientData_LOG_{time.strftime("%Y%m%d")}.log'
today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
yesterday = (today - datetime.timedelta(days=1))
tomorrow = (today + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
#today = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
#yesterday = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# Setup Logging
logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file, filemode='a+', format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)

def decode_sketchy_utf16(raw_bytes):
    s = raw_bytes.decode("utf-16-le", "ignore")
    # s = raw_bytes.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
    try:
        n = s.index('\u0000')
        s = s[:n]  # respect null terminator
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return s
    
def get_write_count(newcount = -1):

    with open(base_folder + count_file, "r+") as cfile:
        count_data = json.load(cfile)
        
        if newcount == -1:
            for c in count_data:
                if c['data'].upper() == 'clientData':
                    return c['count']

        else:
            for c in count_data:
                if c['data'].upper() == 'clientData':
                    c['count'] = newcount

                    cfile.seek(0)
                    cfile.truncate()
                    json.dump(count_data, cfile)
                    break

def write_data(data_queue, columns, columnList):

    try:
        logging.info('starting file write')
        with open(output_file, "w+", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as writecsv:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(writecsv, fieldnames=columnList, delimiter="|", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, extrasaction='ignore', escapechar='\\')
            writer.writeheader()

            while True:
                # print(f'queue size: {data_queue.qsize()}')
                data_rows = data_queue.get()

                if not data_rows or data_rows is None:
                    break

                dataset = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in data_rows]
            
                writer.writerows(dataset)
                data_queue.task_done()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        logging.error(f'Error writing file: {e}')
        logging.info('FILE WRITE ERROR(S)')
        print('Closed with error.')

def export_clientData():    

    with open(base_folder + columns_file, "r") as col_file:
        columnList = col_file.readlines()

    columnList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in columnList]

    get_write_count(0)
    print('Exporting...')
    logging.info('BEGIN EXPORT')

    try:
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxnString)

        with cnxn:
            cursor = cnxn.cursor()
            try:
                cursor.execute(QRY_STR)
                x = 0
                # logging.info('Executed qry.')
            except pyodbc.Error as ex:
                sqlstate = ex.args[1]
                # print(sqlstate)
                logging.error(f'qry: {QRY_STR}')
                logging.error(f'sql_err: {sqlstate}')
                logging.error('Error executing query')
                raise Exception
                # cursor.execute("ROLLBACK")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                logging.error(f'Some cursor execution error: {e}')
                logging.info('END EXPORT WITH ERROR(S)')
                print('Closed with error.')
                return 1

            columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
            TestExportDate = True # boolean for whether we need to test Exported Date
            rcounter = 0
            cnxn.add_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR, decode_sketchy_utf16)

            data_rows = cursor.fetchmany(ROW_BATCH_SIZE)
            data_queue = Queue()

            dataset = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in data_rows]
            if TestExecutedDate == True:
                TestExecutedDate = False
                ex_date = dataset[0]['CLIENT_EXPORT_DATE']
                print(f'Data CLIENT_EXPORT_DATE date: {ex_date}')
                if dataset[0]['CLIENT_EXPORT_DATE'] not in [yesterday, today, tomorrow]:
                    os.remove(output_file)
                    print(f'CLIENT_EXPORT_DATE did not fall on current or previous dates ({yesterday} or {today})')
                    logging.error(f'CLIENT_EXPORT_DATE did not fall on current or previous dates ({yesterday} or {today})')
                    return 1

            with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as threadpool:
                futures = threadpool.submit(write_data, data_queue, columns, columnList)
            
                while data_rows:
                    data_queue.put(data_rows)
                    
                    data_rows = cursor.fetchmany(ROW_BATCH_SIZE)

                    if not data_rows: # or x >= 25:
                        data_queue.put(None)
                        break

                    rcounter += len(data_rows)
                    x += 1
                    if x % 250000 == 0:
                        print(f'rows: {rcounter}')
                    get_write_count(rcounter)

                threadpool.shutdown(wait=True, cancel_futures=False)
                # future.result()
            
            # data_queue.put(None)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        logging.error(f'Error creating odbc connection: {e}')
        logging.info('END EXPORT WITH ERROR(S)')
        print('Closed with error.')
        return 1

    get_write_count(rcounter)
    get_write_count(executed=f'{ex_date}')
    logging.info('END DATA EXPORT')
    print('Finished data Export.')

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':

    export_clientData()
```

EDIT: I've found that if I walk through the code (I'm using VSCode) for the first 5 loops or so, and then let it run, it runs fully and correctly, but if I just call it (from say the command line, or just running fully without any interrupts in VSCode) and run it, it crashes.

Comment: add some more logging to `write_data()`

Comment: I originally had write_data() as a piece not threaded and fully under the `with cnxn:` block; it should have been caught in that, so I don't think it's part of the issue, but I'll certainly wrap it all in a try except block to see if that makes a difference or gives me some info.

Comment: catching exceptions in child threads is often the trick here

Comment: I assume just putting basically everything under def write_data() in a try except block should be enough?

Comment: ya, but make sure to capture the exception so you can properly log it :-)

Comment: It appears unfortunately that that was not the issue.  I updated the the code my my post with the code used, but it still dies silently and suddenly.